# getorgchart sourcedata formatting

Tags: css, json, orgchart

I keep getting az_null errors when adding a json datasource.
I think this is because the ordering of the items getorgchart uses has to be in a specific order and not just correct.

Could you plz let me know what the rules are for this ordering in order for the chart to not throw errors?

e.g below - this will run, so it isnt looking for 'id' to be in order
, but if you place the 3rd time before the second item it'll break it and throw an error.

```
[
    { id: 14, parentId: null },
    { id: 12, parentId: 14 },
    { id: 13, parentId: 12 },
    { id: 11, parentId: 14 },
    { id: 10, parentId: 11 },
    { id: 9, parentId: 11 },
    { id: 8, parentId: 11 },
    { id: 7, parentId: 11 },
    { id: 6, parentId: 11 },
    { id: 5, parentId: 10 },
    { id: 4, parentId: 9 },
    { id:3, parentId: 8 },
    { id: 2, parentId: 7 },
    { id: 1, parentId: 6 }
```

p.s also - how does one make the title fit in the box? i cant edit it in css to wrap or be multiline so the jobs stick out over the edge.

m

Answer (score 0):

The parentId must be defined before the id is defined. In other words, the manager of the employee must be added before the employee is added.

As for the text fields, you can use CSS to set the font size (to fit in the box). For example, class 'get-text-0' is used for the name, and 'get-text-1' for the job title. Here is my custom CSS, for example:

```
.get-org-chart .get-oc-c .get-text-0 {
    fill:#000;        /* font color */
    font-size: 40px;  /* text, Name */
}

.get-org-chart .get-oc-c .get-text-1 {
    fill: #000;       /* font color */
    font-size: 24px;  /* text, Title */
}
```